# Why is the grid-gap ignored on this multi row grid item?

Tags: css, css-grid

Consider the following example:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.container > div {
  min-height: 40px;
}

.item3 {
  grid-row: span 3;
}

.item4 {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.item5 {
  grid-row: span 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item5">5</div>
  <div class="item6">6</div>
  <div class="item7">7</div>
  <div class="item8">8</div>
</div>
```

Why does the `grid-gap` on the 5th element work like that? It looks as if the gap is now part of the element. I would expect that the bottom end of the element would be aligned with the bottom end of the 7th element. The 3rd element works as I would expect. Here's the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/syo30tec/).

**Edit**
If the desired effect is to show the last (implicit) row, the solution is to add `grid-auto-rows: 1fr;`. See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9vexnzb0/).

Comment: because it's trying to span a third row? change it to 2 and it will be consistent along the bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On item 5 you have `grid-row: span 3`.

You only needed `span 2`.

With `span 3`, you've created an extra row, into which the fifth item spans.

Items 7 and 8 aren't set to span that far.

Notice how your grid should have 5 row lines (creating 3 rows), but the `span 3` on item 5 creates an unnecessary 6th row line (creating 4 rows).

[image]

The `span 3` on item 3 works fine.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.container > div {
  min-height: 40px;
}

.item3 {
  grid-row: span 3;
}

.item4 {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.item5 {
  grid-row: span 2; /* adjustment */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item5">5</div>
  <div class="item6">6</div>
  <div class="item7">7</div>
  <div class="item8">8</div>
</div>
```

### The `span` keyword

Keep in mind that `span` counts row / column **lines**.

So referring to the image again:

[image]

- `grid-column: 1 / span 4`, would span across the entire grid, and create one extra column.
- `grid-row: 2 / span 3`, would span down the entire grid, starting at the second row.
- `grid-row: 3 / span 3`, would span down the entire grid, starting at the third row, and create an extra row (like the problem in the question)

[More about the `span` keyword in the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-placement-span-int)

Comment: Wow, ok... What's the reasoning for that? The extra row is not shown and the element _appears_ as if it spans 2 rows.

Comment: The extra row is there. It just has no content inside, and has a default `height: auto`, so it's collapsed.

Comment: Let's say that the grid items are dynamically generated and it's unknown if such a situation might occur. Can this be fixed? Can the extra row be rendered somehow? `grid-template-row` does not seem to work...

Comment: The grid can have author-defined *explicit* tracks. The grid can also have dynamically-created *implicit* tracks. If a grid item is told to span outside the defined (explicit) area, it will automatically create implicit rows and columns to accommodate the expanded grid area.

Comment: Explicit rows are handled by `grid-template-rows`. Implicit rows are handled by `grid-auto-rows`.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. Setting something other than `auto` for `grid-auto-rows` will make the last track visible.

Answer (score 1):

Because `.item5` is only TWO rows tall, not three. The "extra" row is created automatically because you set the span to 3 and thus the extra gap.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.container>div {
  min-height: 40px;
}

.item3 {
  grid-row: span 3;
}

.item4 {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.item5 {
  grid-row: span 2;
  /* not three */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item5">5</div>
  <div class="item6">6</div>
  <div class="item7">7</div>
  <div class="item8">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was so surprised about the gap that I didn't consider looking at the row span... Still, weird and unexpected behaviour.